# How to perform DisplayForModel two times in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my scenario. I've got a partial view called `_QuestionBox` inside of DisplayTemplates. This will render the following

[image]
[image]

I mean, I'm executing DisplayForModel two times but only shows the first one and for the second one ("question-content)" is not displayed. What should I need to be able to execute?

***EDIT***
Let me clarify, that I'm using a class derive from a base one.

**So, the view QuestionBox is for the base class, and the inside display for is for a concrete class.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a View Model in your partial, then you need to pass the model to the partial.

```
@Html.Partial("_partialView", model);
```

Comment: Oh, that's not the problem in that partial.. the problem is it can't show the DisplayTemplate in `DisplayForModel(Question.GetView...)`

Comment: edit your question and paste in code instead of images, then we might be able to help.